# ASA 5505 | 1 public IP - 2 services www, SFTP (PAT)

Tags: cisco-asa, cli

I'm currently trying to reach my LAMP server from the outside.
My LAN server has the IP of 10.255.255.2 and lets say my WAN IP is 84.238.29.84

Shouldn't it just be:

```
objekt network HTTP-PAT
 host 10.255.255.2
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 80 80

access-list outin extended permit tcp any object HTTP-PAT eq 80
```

I tried above, and it does not work.
All I want to (to begin with) is to reach my webserver (10.255.255.2) from outside.

Comment: PAT is really made up. The RFCs use NAPT for what some people call PAT. See _[RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations, Section 4.1.2 Network Address Port Translation (NAPT)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663#section-4.1.2)_: "_NAPT extends the notion of translation one step further by also translating transport identifier (e.g., TCP and UDP port numbers, ICMP query identifiers). This allows the transport identifiers of a number of private hosts to be multiplexed into the transport identifiers of a single external address._" There is more in the RFC.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I've put an example below but with one public IP address you're never going to want to use the NAT Object rules as that assigns the public IP to the host it's going to rather than just the port with the host. Also SFTP transfers over 22 which if you ever want to be able to SSH to the device from the outside and still be able to access the SFTP server you're going to want to use a different port on the outside.

Try using normal static NATs like so instead:

so the an actual rule would look like:

```
object network HTTP_Pub
host 84.238.29.84
object HTTP_Priv
host 10.255.255.2
object service HTTP
service tcp destination eq 80
object service SFTP-ALT
service tcp destination eq 30022
object service SFTP-Int
service tcp destination eq 22
nat (outside,inside) source static any any destination HTTP_Pub HTTP_Priv HTTP HTTP
nat (outside,inside) source static any any destination HTTP_Pub HTTP_Priv HTTP HTTP
access-list outin extended permit tcp any object HTTP_Priv eq HTTP
access-list outin extended permit tcp any object HTTP_Priv eq SFTP-Int
```